# "Cannot load the X.509 certificate identity specified in the configuration"

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, x509

I transfered a workking WCF service from my development environment to the QA environment, including the certificates (Root Authority, Root Auth revocation list, Service certificate - including its PK).

Afterward I located the private key usihg 'FindPrivateKey' and gave all the relavent accounts full permissions to access the private key file at the file system level.

My app crashes with a Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot load the X.509 certificate identity specified in the configuration.

I am stumped, I think I covered everything, but obviously not...

I have tried this on a Windows Service Host as well as a Console App Host. Same issue.

Answer (score 27):

I ran into this same error in a simple WFC service written with VS2010 SP1 on Win 7.  The fix that I found was to add

```
<dns value="localhost" />
```

to the <identity> section of app.config

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wcf/thread/439539ef-e8d7-4e7d-b36e-b80acd401606

Comment: It also worked for me. Just to add that for multiple endpoints you have to add it in all endpoints.

Comment: Don't quite understand, why it could solve the problem, how localhost dns plays in this picture.

Answer (score 8):

this works for me :

```
    <identity>
      <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"  x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="xxxxxxxx" />
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial explaining how to create a certificate that is supposed to remedy this problem:

[Codeplex WCF Security: How To Create and Install Temporary Certificates in WCF for Message Security During Development](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurity/Wiki/View.aspx?title=How%20To%20-%20Create%20and%20Install%20Temporary%20Certificates%20in%20WCF%20for%20Message%20Security%20During%20Development).

Hope that fixes what you needed - even though you asked this 6+ months ago!

Regards,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Does your certificate common name match your host domain name?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to WCF and ran into this issue today when creating a simple WCF service. Just want to share some thoughts:

**1. Fixing the issue -** If you've read all other answers before Joe's (above) you'd know how to fix the issue ;) without the certificates

**2. Fixing the issue with Certificates - I want to thank Joe for sharing a great link** ["How To: Create and Install Temporary Certificates in WCF for Message Security During Development"](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Create%20and%20Install%20Temporary%20Certificates%20in%20WCF%20for%20Message%20Security%20During%20Development)

***Additionally:** [You can download WCF samples from Microsoft website.. You'll find a tool called 'FindPrivateKey' used in the above link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms751450%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)*